# Is it possible in TF/Keras to save the best model AFTER X epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

My models run really fast but they seem to slow down because I'm saving the best model (to load in another process); but I'm noticing the saving process itself slows down the processing. As in the early stages of the fitting each iteration is improving it's adding more and more latency.

I wonder if there is a way to save the best model AFTER X epochs or save it in the background so the model training isn't delayed by saving too often?

For clarity, this is how I'm running `ModelCheckpoint` in Keras/TF2:

```
filepath="BestModel.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
# fit the model
model.fit(x, y, epochs=40, batch_size=50, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `save_freq` argument of [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint) callback to control the frequency of saving. By default, it is set to `'epoch'` which means it would save the model at the end of each epoch; however, it also could be set to an integer which determines the number of **batches** to pass to save the model. Here is the [relevant part of documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint#arguments) for reference:

> **save_freq**: `'epoch'` or integer. When using `'epoch'`, the callback saves the model after each epoch. When using integer, the callback saves the model at end of this many batches. If the `Model` is compiled with `experimental_steps_per_execution=N`, then the saving criteria will be checked every Nth batch. Note that if the saving isn't aligned to epochs, the monitored metric may potentially be less reliable (it could reflect as little as 1 batch, since the metrics get reset every epoch). Defaults to `'epoch'`.

Comment: Thank you - So if I would like to save the best model and have it only process the saving every 10 epochs, I would rewrite my above command to - checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min', save_freq=10)

Comment: @Lostsoul No! When you provide an integer it would count the passed **batches instead of epochs**. You should set it accordingly, e.g. `10 * number_of_batches_in_an_epoch`.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and it looks to work! It looks to have greatly increased my fitting time.

Comment: sorry just to confirm. it's not saving the best model at the 10th epoch..if the best epoch was in between the save_freq, it will save that model?

Comment: @Lostsoul It will save the best model at every N **batches** (not epochs) when `save_freq=N`. Now, since the `loss` value is reset after each epoch then, as stated in the documentation, if the number N is **not aligned with the end of an epoch** you may save a model at the middle of an epoch (to further quote doc: the saving might be as little as 1 batch passed from the start of the epoch, and therefore the monitored metric value may not be very reliable in that case).

Comment: Bad wording on my part - I have aligned the save_freq to be at a number of batches aligned to epochs (num of batches in epoch * 10), I'm wondering does the save occur if the that specific epoch is the best or if the best batch was a few batches previous, it will save that?

Comment: @Lostsoul No, the comparison and model saving only happens at those checkpoints, i.e. save_freq, 2*save_freq, 3*save_freq, etc. You can verify this by looking at the source code ([1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1263-L1264) and [2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/b36436b087bd8e8701ef51718179037cccdfc26e/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py#L1291)).

Comment: ok thanks..my goal was to save the best model after X epochs...I'll play around and see if I can figure a way..this is def helpful right now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Lostsoul why don't you write a custom callback function for your specific task?

Comment: @M.Innat I'll have to look that up. It's strange to me that this does not exist in keras - Save the best model out of all the ones that ran instead of saving the last one. /rant